# 参考ブログ記事: いい「主観的」、よくない「主観的」

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, stackoverflow.blog

英語版Stack Overflowでは聞けないような主観的質問をつっこむためのスピンオフサイト、Programmers SEが2010年にオープンしました。オープン直後は人気投票を始めとした主観的質問の嵐が吹き荒れ (たと聞きます)、これでは最低限のラインを保てない、ということで「建設的な主観的質問」のガイドラインが打ち出されました。

このガイドラインは、ヘルプの[「避けるべき質問」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)ページでも簡単に紹介されているものです。「この質問をもっとよくするには」「もっと役に立つ回答を引き出す書き方をするには」と考えるときに参考になります。

---

## いい「主観的」、よくない「主観的」

[09-29-10 by Robert Cartaino](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Stack Exchangeは、客観的事実にもとづいた質問と回答のための場所である。思い出せる限りの昔から、それもStack Overflowがベータにすらなっていない頃から、僕たちははっきりとそう言い続けてきた。Stack ExchangeサイトのデフォルトのFAQにもしっかりそう書いてある:

> **避けた方がよい質問はありますか？**
>
> 主観的であったり、炎上を招く内容であったり、長々とした議論が必要になるような質問は避けてください。ここは明快な答えが出せるような質問のための場所です！

つまり**回答の出せないような質問、意見・感想のふっかけ合いは主観的すぎるからクローズすべきである**。以上、単純明快、事実万歳、感想・意見は駄目なもの。しかしそもそもこのポリシーの根拠は何だろう？

よく見る掲示板やチャットシステムは、スケーリング上の問題を抱えている。*まったくスケールしない*という問題だ。人が話に加われば加わるほど、ノイズが増える。どんどんノイズが増えていき、突然その日が来る。[何かを学べるような場所ではなくなってしまう](http://scobleizer.com/2009/11/02/the-chat-roomforum-problem-an-apology-to-technosailor/)日が。

> ... いずれ知識を持っている人達（何かといろいろ教えてくれる人達）は○○疲れで去ってしまい、後に残されたものはコンビニの雑誌置き場でしかなくなる。ハーバード大の図書館ではなく。 — Robert Scoble

議論・論争・感想の類は、なかなか楽しませてはくれるものの、多くの掲示板コミュニティの崩壊を招くものだ。Stack Exchangeでは*学び*ということをとことん真面目に考えている以上、こうしたコンテンツを侵入させないためには大いに手間をかける心づもりがある。

客観性を保つべき、と声を大にするのは、計算機や数学の分野ならいいだろう。でも、（比較的）かっちりした学問分野から一歩足を踏み出すと、そこはもう、やわらかな社会科学の分野だ。こうした分野にも専門知識の蓄積はあるけれど、定義上、100%白黒つけられるものじゃない。実際、*ほとんど*の研究分野において客観的な答えというものはない。経済・工学・アート・文学・社会科学といった分野では、完全な正解・不正解はない。主観性のある分野を扱う[Stack Exchange Q&Aサイトのリクエスト](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot)は増え続けていて、もちろんその多くが立派なQ&Aサイトになるだろうと僕たちは考えている！

[image: xkcd 435]

ここからが難しいところだ。

**これまでのポリシーとして、主観的な質問はこの世から消えさるべきもので、絶対に聞いてはいけないものだ、としてきた訳ではない。** ただ単にそうした質問はここでは見送るようにしてきたというだけ。そうした質問を受け入れる掲示板はいくらでもある。

しかし、ソフトウェアやプログラミングの世界も、いつもかつもかっちりしているわけじゃない。「このコードはコンパイルできますか」という類の質問が出尽くしたら、待っているのは「ベストプラクティスは」「使ってみてどうだったか」「特定の環境での振る舞い」といった質問だ。もしかしたら、Stack Overflowコミュニティは質問をしたらすぐに正確な回答が返ってくるサイトに慣れすぎてしまったのかもしれない。主観的な質問を扱うStack Overflowを作る方が他の掲示板にいくよりもいいアイデアだと考え始め、みんなでたまりにたまった[主観的質問をぶつけ合うための姉妹サイト](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)を実際作ってしまった。2年分の主観的質問を詰め込んで、さあ蓋を開けてみたら... どどーん！

[image: programmers.se]

[programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) は一晩で爆発的な広がりを見せた。Stack Exchangeネットワーク全体でみても最高の（そして最悪の）質問が投稿されたものだ。

ページをめくろう。

[Moms4mom](http://moms4mom.com/)はStack Exchange 1.0<sup>*</sup>初期にできたサイトで、主観性の問題についてのいいケーススタディになる。開設者たちは初めから、育児というものは本質的にどこまでも主観的なテーマであって、Stack ExchangeのQ&Aプラットフォームとはまったくそりが合わないと分かっていた。実際、育児は考えられる限りの最も主観的なテーマの一つだと思う。子供は一人一人違うし、親も一人一人違う、そして子供をどう育てるかについての考え方も文化によって*全然*違う。だって、[子供たちと初めてスター・ウォーズ（の全エピソード）をみる時、どの順番でみるのが正解か](http://moms4mom.com/questions/161/what-order-should-i-watch-the-star-wars-saga-with-my-children-for-the-first-tim)なんて、誰が断言できるだろう？

<sup><sup>*</sup> 訳注: Stack OverflowをベースにしたQ&Aサイトを開設できる有料サービスとして2009年にリリースされ、後にStack Exchange 2.0に取ってかわられた。</sup>

Moms4momのユーザー達は主観性の問題に真っ向から取り組み、育児上の主観的な問題について建設的なやり取りをするためのガイドラインを作り上げた: [**「裏付け必須！」**](http://web.archive.org/web/20100610191403/http://moms4mom.com/back-it-up)ガイドラインだ。「裏付け必須！」は、回答する時には以下のいずれかに基づいていなければならない、ということを意味する。

- **個人的**に実際に経験したこと
- 参考資料で**裏付け**できる何か

彼女たちによれば「意見は、ただそれだけではノイズでしかない」。これは主観的意見は表に出さないべき、ということじゃない。本質的に主観的なQ&Aテーマを、建設的で参考になり、役に立つものに方向付けしようとしているのだ。実際分かったのは、**すばらしいQ&Aサイト**を支えるに足る基準を満たす、主観的な専門分野はとても沢山あるということだ。

[image: 客観的・主観的断絶]

もし、*あまりにも主観的すぎる* (ここの判断が難しいところなのだけども) 質問を入り込ませないことができれば、完全に主観的な専門分野を扱うQ&Aサイトであっても、理想的なコンテンツの基準を保つことができる。議論・論争・感想の渦がコミュニティーを乗っ取って、お互いから学ぶはずの場が、体裁はよくとも中身は空っぽなゴシップの集積所に堕ちていくという予定調和的末路をさけることができるだろう。

質問が*どうしようもなく*主観的かというのは、だいたい見ればわかる、と思う。いつもはっきりと説明できるわけではないけど、[見ればそうとわかる](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it)。残念ながら、これだけではガイドラインとして運用するには足りない。

> 今日ここでハードコアポルノを定義する試みはこれ以上いたしません。また、明快に定義することは永遠にできないかもしれません。しかし、一つ言えることは、見ればわかる、ということです。 — ポッター・スチュワート連邦最高裁判事

Stack Exchange上で何を主観的とみなすかもまた、ちょっと主観的な問題だ。けれど、**よい主観性かどうかを判断するためのいくつかのガイドラインは用意できる**。これは[フェアユース](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9)の範囲内かを判断するのと似ている。個々の状況に対して、複数の基準をあてはめて考えてみた上で結論を出すのだ。

### 建設的な主観的質問をするためのガイドライン

1. **建設的な主観的質問は、「なぜ（why）」「どうやって（how）」を説明する答えをひきだす。** ベストな主観的質問は、説明してくれるよう求めるものだ。何かの製品のおすすめを聞きたいとしたら、機能の詳しい解説だけでなく、どうやって使うか、そしてなぜ他のものよりいい製品なのかを聞ければ役に立つだろう。「どうやって？」そして「なぜ？」に関する情報は、単なる機能の抜き書きよりも、さらにはどんなに完全な機能一覧よりも、息が長く価値がある情報だ。対照的に、非建設的な主観的質問は、製品名とリンクだけのような答えを回答者がぽい捨てしていくのを許してしまう。そうした回答は、十分な説明もなければ、コンテキストも背景も教えてはくれない。
2. **建設的な主観的質問は、どちらかというと長い回答がつきやすい。** 短い回答ではない。ベストな主観的質問は、*自分の経験を共有したくなる*ような質問だ。出まかせのような回答文や画像が一つだけ、それもただ単に「最初の回答だったから」というだけのプラス票を稼ごうというような回答なんかではない。経験したことをきちんと共有するには、最低でも段落一つ分の長さは必要だ。理想をいえば数段落だろうか。クッキーの焼き方が知りたいと言ったら、買い物リストは教えてくれなくていい。牛乳、バター、バニラ、卵。そんな無味乾燥で短い食材リストから僕が学べることなんてほとんど何もない。代わりに、*そのレシピで*一番最近クッキーを焼いた時どうだったかを教えて！経験したことを詳しく教えてもらえれば、みんなそこからきっと何か学べるだろう。
3. **建設的な主観的質問は、前向きで公平、中立的な雰囲気がある。** ベストな主観的質問は、誘惑にかられて文句を書き散らしたり炎上を釣るようなことはしない。かわりに、出だしからきちんと、建設的に知識を共有し助け合うための流れを作る。みんなお互いに学ぶためにここにいること、そして本質的に主観的な事柄をどう判断するかについて、一人一人が違う視点や信念を持っていてなお、お互いに学ぼうとしていることを忘れない。言い合いがしたくてここにいるのじゃない、それはみんなの時間を無駄にすることだ。*正しい道は常にいくつもある。*
4. **建設的な主観的質問は、意見より経験を共有する回答をひきだす。** 確かに意見というものは経験に基づいて作られるものだが、ベストな主観的質問はずうずうしくも厚かましいことに、どこから来たかわからない意見よりも、実際の経験を共有してくれと求める。「あなたが何を考えているか」よりも、「何をやったか」を共有してもらった方が役に立つ。誰でも意見ならある。どんなことでも、ただ意見を言うだけなら何の努力も想像力も必要ない。しかし、世界に出ていって何かを本当にやった人、そして背中に傷や矢を背負うことになった経験、これは共有する価値があるといっていい。自分の具体的経験に裏打ちされたものなら、あなた自身の意見を持つあなただけの資格がある。そしてその経験を、もっと言うならその経験から*何を学んだか*を、僕たちとぜひとも共有してほしい！
5. **建設的な主観的質問は、意見というものは事実や参考資料で裏打ちされているべきだと強調する。** 意見だって*全部が*悪いわけじゃない。「専門だから分かります」とか「私がそう言うからにはそうなんです」とか「どうしてもそうなんだ」とかの理由以外の何かで裏付けされていれば、だ。一つ前で書いたように、自分の具体的な経験で裏付けするか、ウェブ上に載せてある自分の調査記録などで、主張を裏付ける証拠になるものを一緒に付けること。もちろん、あなたのことはいい人だと思っているし、あなたのことを信じたいとも思っている。でもウィキペディアと同じく、{{要出典}}。そしてよい主観的質問ははじめからこれを明示する: *裏付け必須！*
6. **建設的な主観的質問は、単なる空っぽの馴れ合いではない。** ベストな主観的質問は、わきあいあいとした自己紹介やただ楽しいだけの馴れ合いの誘惑には乗らない。問題解決のアイデア（一番いい書籍やベストなやり方）をみんなから集めるだけのことがしたくなるユーザーもいる。集まった回答に実際に役立つ知見があるようなものであれば、問題はないだろう。*よくない*のは、自慢しあって絆を深めようといった意図で作られた質問の類だ。「今日見た / した / 食べた中で一番クールな / アホな / 変な / 笑えるものは？」とか、サイトのテーマに関連するキーワードが言い訳のように後付けされた質問、例えば「プログラマーが好きな食べ物は？」のようなものだ。「プログラマーが」を削ってみてもまだ、僕たちの専門分野に特有な問題だろうか？僕らのサイトを訪れる平均的ユーザーが、この質問から何かを学び、よりよい仕事ができるようになると期待できるだろうか？そうでないなら、それは非建設的な主観的質問だ。

さあ、これで全部だ。いい主観的質問とよくない主観的質問の違いを見分けるための、6つのシンプルなガイドライン。もし今、役に立つものかどうか悩んでいる主観的質問があれば、もう悩まなくて大丈夫だ。 **この6つの主観的質問のガイドラインをあてはめてみて、どんな点数になるかを見てみればいい。** 点数が低ければ、クローズしよう。点数が高ければ、プラス投票しよう。来週中くらいには programmers.stackexchange.com でこのガイドラインを徹底するようにする。そしてSEネットワーク全体でも、テーマに主観性が含まれるサイトではポリシーとして運用していく予定だ。

こんなに複雑にしなくたって、と思ってるかな？それも「主観」の範囲内だろう。でも、[Robert Scobleが的確にも指摘したように](http://scobleizer.com/2009/11/02/the-chat-roomforum-problem-an-apology-to-technosailor/)、これは多少の主観性を許しながら、学ぶ場としての僕たちのコミュニティを崩壊から守るための代償だ。学ぶ場としてこそ僕たちはこのコミュニティをかけがえのないものと思ってきたのだから。

僕としては、**主観的質問は終わりだ**、と声を大にして言いたい。そして**主観的質問、万歳**！

---

「xkcd: 純粋さの問題」の使用フォント: [851手書き雑フォント](http://www39.atpages.jp/yagoinienie/851fontpage.html)

Comment: moms4momだけに「彼ら」より「彼女たち」のほうが相応しいかと思って修正してみました。