# 「JavaScriptのフレームワークの選定について」を改善するには

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲, 質問の仕方

[JavaScriptのフレームワークの選定について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2576/30)

にマイナス票がいくつか付いていますが、「おすすめフレームワークを教えてください」というあいまいな質問ではなく、「選び方」に関する質問なので、[建設的な主観的Q&A](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1485/30)になるように気をつければ、こういうQ&Aもよいのではないかと思います。

他のSEサイトの例でいうと、Programmers.SEでは[「フレームワークの選定方法」に関する質問](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+choose+framework)を受け入れています。

現在の質問は

- どのような状況で
- どう考えるか

の2つが無束縛 (限定されていない) な点で、範囲が広すぎるとは言えます。

「このようなユースケースで、JavaScriptのフレームワークを選ぼうとしています。どのような観点から選べばいいでしょうか」と限定すれば、よい質問になると思います。どうでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

問題は「どんなとき」がいくらでも増やせるところにあると考えています。
もちろん代表的なモノは限られるでしょうが、
あれもこれもでずるずると回答が増やせそうなのが気になりました。

Comment: 確かに、そこが広すぎますね。その点を含め、より建設的な話題にするために、質問の方を「改善するには」という方向性にしました。