# 勝手に質問を編集されるのを禁止するオプションが欲しい

Tags: 討議, 編集

てにおは、を直すぐらいなら良いのですがごっそり違う文脈に直されて驚きました。
そういうポリシーとは承知していますが質問の背景は質問した人にしか分からない事も多く他人による大幅な編集はするべきではないと考えています。
もっと言えば明らかな誤字以外に他人が質問を編集する利点が分かりません。
いたらない質問もあると思いますが、そういうものも含めて質問は質問者が全ての責任を負うべきです。
少なくとも質問者が他人によって編集できるかどうか選択できるべきだと思うのですが、どうでしょうか。

Comment: 「ごっそり違う文脈に直されて」というのは具体的にどの質問を指しているのでしょうか？他の人の質問の編集に関しては、レビュー権限を持っている人のレビューによる承認が必要なため、「ごっそり違う文脈に直されて」というような事を出来るだけ防止する仕組みはStack Overflowにはあります。

Comment: 問題を私の質問が編集された事に対する不満に矮小化して理解している人がいますが不適切です。これは StackOverflow 全体に対する議論です。

Comment: 事実確認のために質問しました。「質問者が他人によって編集できるかどうか選択できるべき」かどうかは、メタで議論すればよいと思います。そして「選択できるべき」という声が多ければ運営側に機能追加を依頼すれば良いと思います。

Answer (score 12):

反対します。

私自身、投稿者の意図と違う編集ではないか？と感じるケースは実際にありますし質問者の言いたいことも理解はできます。

しかし`勝手に質問を編集されるのを禁止するオプション`が仮に存在したとすると、誰にも修正不能で独りよがりな質問が増える可能性があります。スタックオーバーフローは質問を投稿して回答を求めるサイトですが、より高尚な目的を抱えていると考えます。まぁ色々とあるでしょうが

- 他の人にも役に立つ(つまり再利用可能な)良質な質問と回答を求めている
- コミュニティによる運営

という点が他のサイトとの大きな違いではないでしょうか。

質問を勝手に編集されて意図が異なってしまうのであれば、再編集をして編集コメントに理由を書くなどで対応は可能です。（編集履歴は公開されており、継続して良くない編集をしていれば、誰の目にもとまるでしょう）
また今回のケースではないですが、悪意のある編集をされた場合もモデレータなどに助けを求めることもできます。
つまり、現時点での機能で十分に対処可能だと言えます。

Comment: システム的な禁止オプション設定には、私も反対です。しかし、2015年1月現在のスタック・オーバーフローでは、質問文面の編集が行き過ぎているとも感じています… システム的に追跡・編集が可能であり、また当サイトの目的がそうであっても、元投稿に対する敬意は払われるべきですね。（この話題は別のメタ投稿をたてるべきかもしれませんが、本回答への支持と追加意見として）

Comment: Wikipediaのような編集合戦を希望しません。率直に言って第3者による編集は迷惑です。
明らかにおかしい、価値のない質問はモデレーターが別途改善を求めるか削除するすればいい問題です。
長く放置されている質問や誤字脱字程度の修正であれば良いと思いますが、現状の文章そのものの改変はいきすぎています。勝手に質問を修正されて本人の意図と異なる文章を私の名前で公開される事を私は希望しません。

Comment: @ぽぽたんさん まず最初のツアーを読まれて「理解者」バッジを獲得されることをおすすめします。「率直に言って第3者による編集は迷惑」なのでしたらそもそもスタックオーバーフローを使わないという選択もあると思うのです。/ 編集合戦は誰にとっても得ではないというのは同感です。

Comment: @yohjp もちろん、敬意は払われるべきだと思います。（すみません、日本語がおかしかったので再投稿しました）

Comment: @ぽぽたん 現在の[利用規約](http://stackexchange.com/legal)上、投稿した内容は[CC-BY-SAライセンス](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.ja)で提供することになっています。サイトの編集機能に関わらず、改変した質問内容を公開される可能性はあります（ライセンス上「変更があったらその旨を示す」こと、とはなっています）。それを希望しない場合は、ライセンスを選択できるようにした方がよい、などの観点からも問題提起をした方がよいです。

Answer (score 11):

編集禁止オプションの追加には、賛同しません。

スタック・オーバーフローの目的は [ツアーページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour) から読み取れる通り、(A)「質問者の技術的疑問が解決される」と同時に、(B)「同じ疑問をかかえる第三者にも有用な回答集となる」ことと考えます。質問者以外の第三者による投稿編集機能は、後者(B)の品質向上ために不可欠な仕組みです。

また本サイト [利用規約(legal)](http://stackexchange.com/legal) に従うと、全コンテンツは [Creative Commons BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)(表示 - 継承 3.0 非移植)  ライセンスとなり、投稿者はこの利用規約に同意済とみなされます。

---

一方で、第三者による投稿直接編集の許容は、大きなリスクも生じ得ると考えています。他意見では割と積極派が多いようですから、以下、編集慎重派の意見として述べます。

（主張を明確にするため一部に強い否定表現を用います。ご理解頂ければ幸いです。）

要旨は次の通りです：

- 質問の編集は、後述ガイドラインに従って行えばよい。ただし、**元質問者の技術的意図から外れる可能性**があるなら、レビュア判断によって再構成を行うのは好ましくない。
- レビュア側に迷いが生じたなら、元質問者とコミュニケーションをとるべき。そうしないなら、単に該当質問を無視するか、反対投票(downvote)や閉じる投票(close)を行えばよい。
- 特にレビュー・プロセスを介さない [質問と回答の編集権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) を持つユーザには、その編集行為に関して十分な配慮が要求されるべき。

後述するリスクは、感情的な側面を抜きにしても、純粋に**技術的な問題**たりえると考えます。議論の発散は望まないため、下記状況を仮定します。

- 本サイトに不慣れな新規ユーザによる質問（≒"初めての投稿"レビューに挙がるもの）
- 投稿は質問者自身の誠意をもってなされた（たとえ的外れ内容や不味い説明でも）
- レビュア自身は該当質問には改善すべき点があると判断した

またレビュー／編集行為に対するガイドラインとして、Meta StackExchangeの ["What are the guidelines for reviewing?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing) / Guidelines for reviewing First Posts を引用します。本メタ回答では 9.Organization と 10.Retitle のみを議論対象とし、それ以外については特段の主張をしません。

> **Common reasons to Edit**
>
> After determining that the post is one that will be useful to the community, take care of:
>
> 1. Remove spurious greetings, declarations of urgency, assurances of having searched and tried stuff (especially if that stuff is nowhere to be seen in the question), promises to appreciate help, requests for links to tutorials for one who is just getting started and the like.
> 2. Not enough paragraph breaks, or too many
> 3. Identify an actual question, usually at the beginning or the end of the question. If it must be in the middle, consider highlighting it in some fashion.
> 4. Code not formatted as code, whether inline or in blocks
> 5. Attempts at bulleted or numbered lists that don't use markdown
> 6. Raw links or "click here" or "this" links - the display text should be descriptive, like The MSDN Documentation or A Tutorial on Exceptions. Hover or follow the links to rule out spam.
> 7. Pictures or code hosted offsite - open them in a new tab. If they're appropriate, bring them into the question. For code, you may need to know the language or technology to know what to bring in. If you don't know it, you can leave a comment instructing the author to make that edit.
> 8. Spelling, grammar, and punctuation, as well as spacing oddities like space before comma
> 9. **Organization: many first timers have 3-4 paragraphs of talk, then all the code. Organize things correctly to increase readability and understanding of the question**
> 10. **A title which actually describes the question**
> 11. Remove any sort of rudeness; make the post courteous and helpful.
>
> After fixing all of that, if there is still more missing (for example what operating system is being used), then add a comment requesting the details be edited into the question. A comment to a new user that only asks a question will typically be answered in comments. Explain our normal procedures to them.

---

レビュアにはいくつか行動オプションが与えられます。このうち 1.編集行為 のみで、他オプションでは生じえない「質問者の本来の意図から逸脱した技術質問に書き換わるリスク」が生じます。

1. 質問の文面を編集(edit)し、あれば追加コメントを残す。
2. 質問に反対投票(downvote)し、あれば追加コメントを残す。
3. 質問を閉じる投票(close)し、あれば追加コメントを残す。
4. 質問へコメント追加し、文面／内容の改善を求める。
5. 質問の意図をくみとり、相応の回答を付ける。
6. 何もしない／無視する。

他意見にもある通り、全ての投稿文面はCC BY-SAライセンスで供され、また本サイトの目的(B)からいっても編集行為は正当化されます。しかしレビュアによる翻訳・解釈と文面再構成が行われ、元質問者の技術的意図から逸脱したならば、それは「質問者の真意＋編集者の解釈が合成されたキメラ質問」となり、真の技術的疑問から遠ざけることで**本サイトの目的(A)を毀損**しています。これは技術的側面からいって、許容されるべきではありません。

当然レビュアに"悪意"は無いものと仮定しますが、私の主張は「レビュア個人の考えによる**善意の文面編集**には、質問者への**技術的な悪意**たりえるリスクがある」という点です。全ての翻訳・解釈・再構成がNGとは言っていません。特に単独で編集可能な権限をもつユーザには、リスクを考慮した慎重な編集行為を行ってほしいのです。

---

システム的には再訂正可能であり、編集の全履歴も記録されているという反論に対しては、質問が投稿されてから回答が集まるまでの時間軸と、CC BY-SAライセンスとサイト上での投稿の見え方を反駁論拠とします。

仮に質問者意図に反していても、後で元質問者が修正すればよい：

- 質問投稿がなされてから回答が付くまでの**時間軸**を考慮すると、これは誠実な考え方とはいえません。
- サイトトップに投稿時間／アクティブ順で表示されることもあり、回答投稿は質問投稿から比較的短期間に集中すると考えられます。しかし、これらは"キメラ質問"に対する回答にすぎず、元質問者の技術的疑問を解消しません。（他の"誰か"には有用かもしれませんが）
- 元質問者が文面を再修正するタイミングを、レビュアや回答者が知ることは不可能です。レビュア編集の直後かもしれませんし、明日かもしれませんし、1週間後かもしれません。不慣れなユーザのため、再編集が出来ることも知らない可能性が高いです。"キメラ質問"が放置される物理的時間が長くなるほど、技術的に適切でない状態が継続し拡大されていきます。

全ての編集履歴は保存され、また追跡可能なシステムである：

- 大部分の閲覧者は、表面的にしか質問／回答を見ないと考えるべきです。元質問者が置かれた状況に照らすと、履歴の存在をもって十分とするのは誠実といえません。
- 投稿された質問は、質問文面＋元質問者ID（＋最終編集者ID） の組で表示されます。システム的には履歴機能から編集時系列を遡れますが、サイト上での見た目は、常に 質問文面＋元質問者ID であることに強く配慮すべきです。
- 利用規約では[CC BY-SAライセンス](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)で **"帰属(Attribution)"** を明言しており、編集後の質問文面もまた 元質問者ID に帰属します。本サイト上の表示形式を踏まえると、"キメラ質問"文面＋元質問者ID という状況は、存在してはならないと考えます（これはコメント追記で緩和可能と考える）。元質問者の視点に立てば、レビュアの善意とは反対に、自身に帰属すべき投稿への技術的な内容改ざんと解釈されます。

---

最後に念のため補足しておくと、全ての質問に賛成投票(upvote)や適切な回答が付くべきだ、という主張はしません。コミュニティから有用性が認められない質問や品質改善が望めない質問、不適切投稿などは一定数存在し、それらは反対投票／クローズ／削除等されて然るべきです。先に挙げたレビュアの"善意"は、直接編集によって質問を救うという考え方に近い気がします。それ自体はコミュニティにとって有用かもしれませんが、既に述べた危険性も内包すると繰り返したいと思います。

Comment: 本文補記：当初は感情的な側面も付けようと考えていたのですが、あまりに長くなり過ぎるので省略しました。感情的側面の本質は単純で、「せっかくの新規ユーザを委縮させないようにしようよ」「コミュニティの新陳代謝は常に必要です」程度です。なお、この主張は過敏すぎるというご意見には同意します。おそらく、某技術情報共有サイトへの投稿で運営側から非公開措置（検閲）をうけた体験が色濃く反映されています。誹謗中傷的な投稿内容でなく、純粋に外縁技術に触れた投稿でしたが、運営判断でサイト意向には沿わないとの回答でした。検閲・改竄を受ける側の衝撃というのは、なかなか想像しがたい部分があります。本サイトの新規ユーザが、受ける側の主観として同種体験をしないことを望んでいます。

Comment: おっしゃるとおりで、厳密なルール適用を新規ユーザにぶしつけに適用すると、せっかく来ていただいた方が気分を概して定着しないってことは起こりえますね。
まだコミュニティが小さい中で、こうしたユーザ離れは長期的に見てマイナスになることは間違いないので、まずはなるべく親切にコメントを付けるようにしようと思いました。

Answer (score 6):

このオプションの設置については反対します。編集は Stack Overflow の重要な要素です。

初投稿は、改行／フォーマット／題名に配慮がされていないものが多く、それが放置されるかどうかで、サイトの全体の第一印象と質は左右されます。 以下の２サイトを見比べてみてください。違いを生み出した要因の一つには、強力な編集機能の有無があったのではないでしょうか。

- [TeraTail "プログラミング"](https://teratail.com/questions/search?q=%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0)
- [スタックオーバーフロー: "プログラミング"](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0+is%3Aquestion)

細かく編集履歴は取られていますので、編集にバイアスがあるのか、悪意がある人物によるのかはチェックできるはずです。私の編集が気になるのなら、私の編集記録を見てください。「心外な編集」については、ロールバックを使ってください。対処ができなければ meta に投稿か、 モデレーターを呼んでください。

以下、当事者なので手元のログのダンプ。

#### □ 該当の質問

- [async/awaitを使った非同期プログラミングにおいてコレクションの変更を行う際のベストプラクティスは](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/5622/revisions)

#### □ 質問を編集した目的

1. [async-await](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await) タグの追加
2. Async/Await は VisualBasic の用語であるから、C# の async/await に変える
3. C# の非同期処理に置けるキーワードに MSDN へのリンクを張り、対象の回答者には回答しやすく、C# 以外のエキスパートが、純粋な技術的興味からも質問に食いつけるようにする
4. プログラム内に出現するキーワードをコードとしてマークアップする
5. 改行をつめ、段落の調整を行い、可読性を上げる
6. 題名を短くして質問一覧での見栄えを良くする
7. 主観的な回答を呼び込む「ベストプラクティス」の記述を、早い段階で取り除く

ぽぽたんさん が問題にされたのは、私が題名を書き換えたことです。

題名は『「ベストプラクティス」の記述をなくし、できるだけ簡潔にする』ことを目的に書き換えられました。かなり悩みましたが、最終的に「ベストプラクティス」部分を変更するように背中を押したのは、初投稿でも題名が長く、改行もどう直すべきか悩んだ前回の記録があったことと、ぽぽたんさんが理解者バッジを持っていなかったことです。

#### □ 「ベストプラクティス」について参考資料

- [参考ブログ記事: いい「主観的」、よくない「主観的」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485/%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E8%A8%98%E4%BA%8B-%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-%E4%B8%BB%E8%A6%B3%E7%9A%84-%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E4%B8%BB%E8%A6%B3%E7%9A%84)
- [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing)
- [Best-Practices versus Subjective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37682/best-practices-versus-subjective)
- [The “best practice” answer etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145909/the-best-practice-answer-etiquette)
- 英語版 Stack Overflow ["best practice" の検索結果は墓場](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=best%20practice)

この投稿は短く編集されています。[編集前のものは編集記録で見られます](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1631/2)。

Comment: 私も件の質問に回答した後で文脈が大幅に変わっていることが疑問だったのですが、設計を問う広範な内容だったものが「ループ」という具体的な表現に変わったことでニュアンスが限定されてしまったていたように感じました。私以外の回答も編集前のenigmaさんは広範なツリー操作を想定しているのに対して、編集後のPITAさんのものは単一ICollectionに限定されているように見えます。

Comment: これは私個人の1つの質問の問題ではありません。
長文で読みにくい上不適切な回答なので削除して下さい。

Comment: @pgrho 意図して範囲を狭めました。題名の対象とする範囲が広く、本文が対象とする範囲が狭い。では本文にあわせましょうと考えました。やりすぎてるな、と感じられましたら、戻してください。お手数かけるのは申し訳ないですが。

Comment: @ぽぽたん 議論の種としての投稿です。「なぜ、あなたが気分を害し、 meta に投稿することになったかの経緯」「なぜ私が投稿を編集したのか」を把握するための情報です。原因調査の参考になるように、手元のログを、ダンプしました。しかし、長文で読みにくいのは確かなので、短くしますね。（全文を読みたければ編集履歴をクリック）「ベストプラクティス」については、リンクだけを残し、別の機会に meta に投稿することにします。

Comment: 質問文面を変更して「範囲を狭める」のではなく、コメントをつけて意図を確認するという手段もありえます。そのようなコミュニケーションの後にベストプラクティスに近づけていった方が、結果的にはトラブルになりにくいと思います。いきなり自身のアウトプットを修正されるというのは、たとえそれが正しくても、必ずしも気分がいい物ではないという考えもあります。

Comment: @yohjp 変更前にコメントを残し、確認を取って変更することが良いと考えています。全ての投稿について十分にコミュニケーションが行われ、その結果質問の質が向上することが理想的と思います。現実にはそのための時間はとれませんから（コメントしてるうちにマイナス票が付きますし）、私は、個人的なワークフローに対象ユーザの活動確認やバッジ確認をはさみ、[ケースバイケースで対応し](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/4978/hiroshi-yamamoto?tab=activity&sort=comments&page=2)ています。それでも、コメントを付けること自体がトラブルを呼ぶことがあります。[こんな感じ](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/4712/revisions)で一時的にかなりショックな状態になります。このような状態は避けたい。 /// 文の並び替え等軽微な変更を除き、私が質問本文の文面を変えることはありません（例外は[このような投稿](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/5227/revisions)）。それを踏まえて理解していただきたいです。私として、今回の反省点は「題名は黙々と無制限に手をつけるべき」としていたことと認識しましたので、そこについて手順を変更し改善をします。

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto 全てをご自身でチェックされる必要は無いと思います。私個人としては、"文の並び替え"も極力避けるべき事項と考えています。スタック・オーバーフローは技術質問の場であって、日本語添削の場ではありませんから。もちろん、日本語として読み易い質問の方が反対票が付きにくく、良回答がつきやすくなることは同意します。しかし、あまりにうるさく文面修正がなされてしまうと、質問者の心証としては決してプラスに働かず、（特に）新規ユーザを萎縮させるリスクも考えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 現状の修正はやり過ぎています。（一応）客観的事実を記載するWikipediaと違ってスタックオーバーフローの質問は質問者の意図が強く反映されています。つまり絶対的な正解はありません。たとえ日本語としておかしかったとしてもそれが質問者の意図である可能性もあります。つまり原則として誤字脱字や表記の揺れを除き第3者が改変するべきではないと考えています。
本家でどうやってたかは知らず。履歴なんて一々チェックしてないからね。

Comment: @yohjp 文面修正に対するユーザの心証は悪いものであることは同意しますが、その必要性について、私の見解と異なっています。あちらでは、「よろしく」「ありがとう」が自動で削除されたり、不特定多数から編集されたり、「ベストプラクティス」が数時間でクローズされたりする具合で、質問への要求が厳しい。それをふまえて、私はそのようなことをいきなりしないが、質問の投稿直後に、フォーマットをただし、語順を変えることは良いことだと（軽く）考えていました。 /// 私は、せっかく機会が与えられているのだから、英語版SOの手法を段階的に日本版にローカライズできればと考えています。 レビューをする際にも、「承認」「承認」「承認」「承認」と続けていくのは楽ですが、この回答中の Teratail サイトを見ればわかる通り、「何もしないで質の低い質問を見過ごすリスク」は非常に大きいと考えています。今のように、編集行為が怖がられて、実践されないなら、私がやりますし、行動で示しますし、質を上げるためなら憎まれても良いと考えました。 /// ですが、 yohjp さんの意見をくみ、私は、編集を少し自重するようになることをお約束しますよ。 （1000+ も多くなってきましたし、代わりに誰かやってください！）

Comment: @ぽぽたん お気持ちを理解しているつもりです。 一点、根本的な見解の違いが生まれる原因に気づきました。共有させてください。 Stack Overflow は、「局所的なトピックを対象とした質問と、それに対する明確な回答が含まれたページが終わりなく作られ続ける Wikipedia」と言えます。 Wikipedia のようなものです。 重複は排除され、主観的な事柄を嫌われ、客観的な事柄にフォーカスが当てられる場です。だからこそ、件の「ベストプラクティス」は私にはグレイゾーンと認識されました。 また、第３者による編集については「技術的に可能な編集はすべて実践されることになる。ただし、コンテンツの内容は作成者への尊敬をもって守られるべき」 と考えています。そのように作られていますから。ここはもやもやしますが、うまくことを運ぶためには、まず全員がある程度システムへの理解をもつことと、止まらない善意が必要だと思います。

Comment: こちらのコメント交換を通じて、私自身もやもやしていた部分が固まったので、新ためて回答として追加しました。ありがとうございました。P.S.：[1回目コメント](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1630/1644#comment618_1631)時点では「"SO上で質問する場合の"ベストプラクティス」という妙な脳内補完をしており、該当箇所は意味が通らない文になっていました。お詫びして訂正しますm(_ _)m

Answer (score 6):

「少なくとも質問者が他人によって編集できるかどうか選択できるべきだ」に関しては反対します。理由は以下の２点です。

- そもそもスタック・オーバーフローというサイトの目的が「どの質問に対してもベストアンサーを用意する事」であり、その目的のために質問や回答の編集を推奨しているから（サイトの目的に関しては[ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)を参照）。
- 質問者の意図に沿わない修正に関しては、対応する手段が用意されているから（質問者による再編集、ユーザによるレビュー、メタによる議論等）。

Comment: 開設初期でやる気に満ちあふれているせいか、現状では編集がいきすぎています。質問者の意図と異なる編集はいくら何でもNGです。
現状では不適切な編集に対処するすべがありません。

Comment: まず「現状では編集がいきすぎています」という具体例を示してください。また「不適切な編集に対処するすべ」は私の回答に記載したようにあると考えています。「すべがない」という場合には具体的になぜすべがないかを示してください。

Comment: 改ざんする方は1万人で質問者は1人です。防衛するコストと攻撃するコストがまるで見合っていません。悪意ある編集に対して対抗できる現実的な方法がありません。

Comment: コミュニティをもう少し信頼しましょう。「改ざん」という言い方には問題があると考えます。

Comment: @ぽぽたん 「悪意ある編集」は現状ほとんどないと思いますし、あってもレビューや再編集、メタの通報等で対応可能と考えます。

Comment: 個人的にはぽぽたん氏のいう「悪意」「改ざん」に賛同できる部分が少なからずあります。私の考えと回答として追加しました。

Answer (score 6):

他の方と同じく、タイトルにある「編集を禁止するオプション」には反対です。

この提案の根本にあると思われる「質問者が不愉快に感じる編集がなされることがある」という問題は、編集によるコミュニケーションを減らす方向ではなく、既存の対応手段を含めコミュニケーションを増やす方向で解決していく方が、結果的により役立つサイトになると思います。

「既存の対応手段がある」という点は他の方が回答していますので、この回答では問題提起文に対するダイレクトな意見を述べます。（コメントで言及しやすいように一文ずつラベル付けしてあります。）

> A. そういうポリシーとは承知していますが質問の背景は質問した人にしか分からない事も多く他人による大幅な編集はするべきではないと考えています。

これは編集内容によると思います:

**質問者が知りたいこと**からズレてしまうような編集は、するべきではないと思います。  
<sub>// 実装を変えてしまった結果、テストが通らなくなる状況と同じ、と考えられます。</sub>

**質問者が知りたいこと**はキープしつつ、**質問の聞き方**を改善する編集はOKだと思います。

例えば、聞き方がオフトピックとみなされるものだったり、一般的心象がよくない言い回しがあったりして、回答がつかないだろうと思われる場合があります。そういう時に、編集して聞き方を改善することで、回答がつくような形にもっていくことができますし、有用なQ&AコンテンツをStack Overflowに追加する結果にもなります。

このように、聞き方を変える範囲での「大幅」な編集は、メリットがあるものだと思います。  
<sub>// 実装をリファクタリングしつつ、テストが通る状態を保つのと同じ、と考えられます。</sub>

大幅な編集によって新規ユーザーを遠ざけてしまう可能性がある、というデメリットは、編集の意図を編集サマリーやコメントで説明することで緩和できるのではないかと思います。私は編集サマリーには変更点だけでなく、何故その変更をしたかをなるべく書くようにしています。
<sub>// コードのコメントやコミットメッセージで、何故その修正をしたのかを説明するのと同じ、と考えられます。</sub>

> B. もっと言えば明らかな誤字以外に他人が質問を編集する利点が分かりません。

利点がある場合として以下のケースも考えられます。

- 質問のタイトルや内容で一見分かりにくい箇所があった場合、その場で編集して改善することができる
- 質問者がコメント欄でのみ言及した補足情報や要件があった場合、質問を編集して追加しておくことで参照性を高めることができる

<sub>// ソースコードを読んだ時に、分かりにくいところがあったらリファクタリングしておくのと同じ、と考えられます。</sub>

> C. いたらない質問もあると思いますが、そういうものも含めて質問は質問者が全ての責任を負うべきです。

いたらない質問をどうすれば改善できると思うかを伝えるのに、実際に編集してみせるのはとても有効な手段です。質問者は自分の言葉で書いた質問なので理解できていても、他人が読むと分かりにくい文面になっていることもあります。 
<sub>// ペアプロ中に、横から口で言っていても伝わらないのでキーボードを奪うのと同じ状況、と考えられます。</sub>

また、編集にかける時間と手間を多くの人に分散させることで、質問者一人に編集を任せるよりも早く質問の質を上げていくことができます。これは、ほとんどのユーザーは善意にもとづいて行動しているということを前提にしています。ほんとうに悪意をもったユーザーは、モデレーターの判断次第で参加を禁止することができます。

> D. 少なくとも質問者が他人によって編集できるかどうか選択できるべきだと思うのですが、どうでしょうか。

編集禁止オプションを選択したすべてのユーザーが責任を持って質問を保守するとは限らない、ということを考慮する必要があると思います。

そうしたユーザーが残していった、編集ができない質問について:

1. そのままでもよい質問だが、誤字脱字がある場合: 改善する機会を失います

   編集できず、削除するにはしのびないので、そのまま放置することになると思われます。
2. そのままではよくない質問だが、編集でよい質問にできる場合: 改善する機会を失います

   上で書いたような、質問の聞き方を変えた方がよい場合です。編集して改善できない以上、クローズ・削除することになると思われます。編集した上でよいコンテンツをサイトに加えるという機会を失うことになります。

ユーザーが後から戻ってくるか分からないネット上のコミュニティーで、質問者が全ての責任を負うモデルを部分的にでも採用すると、質が改善されないままのコンテンツを誘い入れることになると思います。そうしたコンテンツを放置・削除するよりは、編集で改善する道が残されている方がよいと考えます。  
<sub>質問者が責任を負うことにした質問は、[トラックナンバー](http://www.wdic.org/w/TECH/%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%8A%E3%83%B3%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC)が 1 のプロジェクトと同じ、と考えられます。</sub>

Answer (score 1):

結構意見がぶら下がっていますが。私の個人の「気がかり」を述べます。

### 編集の目的とは

意見の中で「ツアー」の話題が出ましたが。ツアーでは「編集機能を使って、間違いを修正したり、書式を改善したり、投稿の意味をはっきりさせます」とあるように、本来は校正が目的であること私は考えています。（コメント等のやりとりで追加情報が出てきて、投稿者が本文修正忘れた場合などの代理修正なども校正の一種とします）また無査読編集権限でも「意味の変更はしない」と明文化されています。
（参考：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit）

もし目的外修正が目立つようであれば。それはサイトの信頼を損ねる行為なので何かしらの対応が必要でしょう。

### 目的外編集は横行しているの？

編集時の注意喚起や。編集理由の必須かなどあるでしょうが。
私は、既にある編集に対する査読が一定の効果があると信じています。
（参考：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit）

しかし「無査読での編集が適切かどうか誰がチェックできるのか」がまったくわかりません。（もし御存知でしたら是非コメントで説明されているページを教えてください！）

### 質問への否定的意見

編集はリビジョンで見ることができます。また誰が査読を承認したかもリンクを辿れば確認できます。しかし知らないユーザーは多いのではないでしょうか（ヘルプのどこかにも編集日時のリンクから履歴辿れるみたいなのチラっと書いてあったはずですけどね）。
不案内気味であることは認めた上で。システム上は大きな問題は生じていると認めがたいです。
（参考： https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/7028/revisions）

### 質問への肯定的意見

無査読で行われた編集に対する保護策が私には見えません。もちろん信頼度を獲得していますから編集は許可されるべきでしょう。これらの対応は大きく３つです。

１．無査読を無くす。
　査読人数に差をつけるだけでよく。査読者０人の状況だけ無くせばいいという考え方です。
２．苦情の申立を分かりやすくする。
　少なくともモデレーターの負担を考えると。履歴に通報ボタンをつけるべきです。
　しかしモデレーターは例外処理ですし。多くの通報が投げ込まれる可能性が高いので積極的な意見にはできません。
　（参照： https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators）
３．投稿者が編集禁止を選択可能とする
　結局のところ無査読編集者と投稿者がファイトするようであれば投稿者が編集禁止を選択可能とすべきです（どうせファイトしたら通報してロックされるでしょ！）。
　**あるいは、投稿者によるロックには、高い信頼度を消費させる**というのもいいですね。
　ところで既出意見の中でCCライセンスに言及している意見がありますが。CCBYSAは、スタックオーバーフローの中でそのページが編集不可能となることには、何ら問題が生じません（どうぞ"複製して"翻案してください）。とはいえ履歴が残っている以上は、複製して翻案して投稿しているんですけどね。その投稿を、スタックオーバーフローのシステムとして受け入れるかどうかは、ライセンスとは関係ありません。（その制御を投稿者本人が行うことの是非は揉めそうですが）

### 個人的な結論

無査読を無くすのが精一杯だと思います。（私は、今のところ困っている状況じゃないので私から提案はしませんが。提案があれば私は賛成します）

Comment: 長い説明ありがとうございます。基本的に、当サイトのスタンスは信用度のあるユーザーを信頼すべきですので、無査読でいいです。もし悪用な編集が行われた場合：①　編集時に投稿者への通知が来ます（悪用な編集なら投稿者が自分の質問を治せたり、通報することができます）　②　投稿が編集させると、メインページのトップに上がります。その質問を読む人が気づいたら、通報・編集することができます。③　同じ質問が複数回編集された場合、自動的にモデレーターに通知します。もし問題があれば、モデレーターが対応出来ます。もし、編集のハードルを上がると、編集する人が減りますし、編集のかわりに新しい回答を追加したり、コメントでその情報を置いたりしますので、回答を探しているユーザーにより不便になると思います。

Comment: ①と②は疑問ですが。③は私の求めていた答えかもしれません。　 ①投稿者が自分の質問を再修正することにより結局殴り合いが起きます。また現状の通報はUI的に「質問自体に対するもの」なので通報に抵抗感があります(軽く思ったんですがせめて This Questionを「この質問のやりとり」とかにするだけで違いがありそうです。翻訳に関することなので別に要望出しますね)。　②メインページのトップにあがったところで「編集が何回繰り返されたか」は履歴を見ないと分かりにくいです。また興味のない質問はそもそも流されやすいでしょう。③この通知処理で私は安心できました。　しかし今説明されるまで「そういう通知が行われる」ということは、言われるまでわかりません（まあ頻度が少ないのであれば都度説明すれば良いという考えもあるでしょうが…どこかに説明ありますでしょうか？）。

Comment: 人間が悪い例を覚えながら、いい例をすぐ忘れてしまう現象があります。１００件の良い編集より、ひどい編集が頭に残り、編集に対して保守的になってしまうおそれがあります。悪い編集の頻度が多かったら（いい編集と比較して）それはもちろん治すべきです。もし複数の事例や統計があれば、共有してくれますか？[データエクスプローラー](http://data.stackexchange.com/)を利用できます（英語ですが、SQLを理解すれば問題ないと思います）。

Comment: たしかに。私は今まさにそれ（人間が悪い例を覚えながら、いい例をすぐ忘れてしまう現象）に取り憑かれているかもしれません。事例を調べるというのも大事ですね。ものすごく心が軽くなりました。ありがとう。

Comment: あー。ここで聞くべきか悩みましたが。 http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/295354 こういう感じでしょうか？（変更内容を考慮していないので数は多めに出るはずですが、想像よりずっと少なかったです）