# 回答にいくつか付け加えて解決した場合、回答を編集してもよい？

Tags: 討議

得られた回答そのままでは問題が解決できなかったものの、それを参考に、あるいはアレンジすれば解決できた、という場合に次のような選択肢が考えられます。

- 完全な解決策を自分で回答する [例1](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/7692/8000) [例2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/5777/8000)
- 得られた回答を編集して書き加える　[例1](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/9063/revisions) [例2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/5943/revisions)
- 特にまとめることはしない・コメントのみ

まずQ&Aとして見た場合、Qに直接対応するAが承認済み回答として大きく見えた方が、後から見る人にはわかりやすいでしょうから、何かしらまとめてあった方がよいと思います。

投稿の編集は基本的に「内容を変えずに改善する」ものだと思っていたので、質問した側の都合で「内容を付け足す」ことに少し違和感を感じました。とはいえ自己回答する場合、ほとんど同じ内容の回答が増える可能性がありますし、手柄の横取りに見えるかもしれません。

得られた回答を質問者が編集することについて、皆さんはどう思われますか？

関連 [勝手に質問を編集されるのを禁止するオプションが欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1630/8000)

Answer (score 3):

得られた回答を下地にして解決できたのなら、その回答の末尾に追加で行った作業を追記すればいいでしょう（手順が大幅に異なっているなら、新しい回答をじぶんで投稿すればいいです）。不完全な回答を完全な回答へと編集することに、当該質問者、当該回答者、第三者を区別するメリットはありません。

将来の検索者が求めているのは「誰の回答か」という価値ではなく、質問と回答の整合性と回答が始終のすみずみまで正しく効果的であることだと思います。Stack Overflowで検索するとき、誰の質問で誰の編集か気にしますか？　じぶんはしません。

> 投稿の編集は基本的に「内容を変えずに改善する」ものだと思っていたので、質問した側の都合で「内容を付け足す」ことに少し違和感を感じました。

じぶんは「得られた回答を編集して書き加える 例2」の張本人です。この質問はObjective-CのタグをつけObjective-Cのコードで質問しましたが、Swiftによる回答がありました。この場合、SwiftとObjective-Cを理解できるのなら、Objective-C版のコードを回答に追記することはObjective-Cのタグで検索する人にとっては有益です。行ったのが、たまたま質問者自身だっただけです。また、既存の回答文は何も変更していません。

こういった編集にも違和感を感じますか？　その違和感は、何が「間違っている（スタックオーバーフローにとっての不利益がある）」と考えてのものですか。具体的な不利益が思い浮かばないのであれば、あなたにとっては違和感を感じるものでも、妥当な行いかもしれません。

Comment: コミュニティWiki回答であったり、一つの回答を皆で改善していくスタイルであれば仰る通りだと思います。それらとは違い、一応回答者がクレジットされている以上、極端な話「俺はそんなこと言っていないのに」と思われることがないだろうか、という感じですね。勿論それを突き詰めると投稿の編集なんてできなくなってしまうので、さじ加減に迷った次第です。