# 「〜の次期メジャーバージョンアップの目玉機能は何か？」という質問は主観的か

Tags: 討議, クローズ理由

私が投稿したこの質問に対して、「主観的な答えしか集まらない」という投票が集まり「改善待ち」になりました。
[Apache Camel 3（次期メジャーバージョンアップ）での目玉機能は何になりますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/39443/apache-camel-3-%E6%AC%A1%E6%9C%9F%E3%83%A1%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E7%9B%AE%E7%8E%89%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)

しかし、あるライブラリのメジャーバージョンアップについて、その注目機能は何か‌​、という質問が主観的な回答しか得られない‌​、という指摘が理解できません。どんな‌​ライブラリも、メジャーバージョンアップを‌​するならそれなりに客観的なコンセンサスの‌​得られた注目機能があるものだと思うからです。少なくとも、それを開発している当事者の中では、主にどの機能の追加を目指して開発している、というリストはあるはずです。

もし、上記のような質問で、こうしたらもっと客観的な回答が得られやすい、というような建設的なご提案があればぜひお願いします。

また、私の言っていることが理に適っている、ということであれば、上記質問の「改善待ち」状態の解消をお願いします。

（このメタ質問は、今後同じような質問をされる方のためのガイドラインになることも期待して、メタに投稿しました。）

Comment: やはり注目機能を決めるときに主観が入っちゃいますよね… って回答しようとしたら既に回答されてましたね… あ、開発者側から見てっていう質問なら主観は入りにくいかもしれませんよー

Comment: 私の感覚では、「目玉商品」を何にするのかを決めるのは店側であって客では無いです。
この感覚で「目玉機能」について考えると、決めるのは開発者側であって、利用者では無いと思います。
ですから、「目玉」を聞いているから主観的だとは思いません。
しかし、意見が割れている状態で、「目玉」の解釈を議論するのも不毛ですから、補足や言い換えによって質問を改善するのがよいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「開発者から見て」と明示するといい、というのはその通りですね。元質問は、そのご指摘に基づいて少し編集してみます。

Comment: （返信機能の誤用、およびそれに関するコメントを整理しました）

Answer (score 15):

クローズの是非はともかくとして感想です。

まず、「目玉」が何かは人によって異なります。

- その人にとって欲しかった新機能
- その人にとっては致命的だったバグの修正
- その人にとっては問題だったパフォーマンスの改善

こういう主観的な観点の回答がついた中で、どれがベストかを選ぶのも質問者の主観になってしまいます。

主観的な観点を廃して網羅的な内容を回答することも可能かもしれませんが、それはもはやリリースノートなどのデッドコピーや要約、それらの翻訳に過ぎないでしょう。

リリースノートの内容に解説を付け加えた回答だとどうでしょう。それは質問を前提とせず自分のブログやQiitaなどに独立した内容の記事として書ける内容でしょう。

自分で回答するのであればある程度そういった内容でも許容されるかなと思いますが、質問の内容次第です。質問そのものか、それに紐付く回答が興味深いものであればプラスの評価になることもあるでしょう。

---

承認システムが正しく運用されていないケースがあるのは事実ですが、概ね適正に機能しているのではないかと思います。また、そのようなケースがあるからといって、「主観的な回答しかあつまらない」質問は好ましくないというSOのポリシーそのものが成り立たない事にはなりません

---

上で「自分で回答するのであれば許容される余地がある」というのは、自分で回答するのであれば質問と同時または間を置かずに回答可能で、質問と回答の質が十分高ければクローズせずとも他の雑多な回答を抑止することが期待できる、ということです。

雑多なゴミが集まったとしてもその中に宝物が紛れているかもしれない、そうであればその質問は良い質問だ、というのはSOのポリシーではなく、そのためのクローズの機能だと思っています。この思想を変更する必要があるとは感じません。

---

回答を前提として質問を考えるとするとこんな感じでしょうか

> Apache Camel 3(次期メジャーバージョンアップ)に向け、開発チームが主なターゲットとしている項目はなんですか

回答を見る限り書きたいのは「アーキテクチャの刷新」「APIの明確化」でしょうから、「目玉機能は何か」という質問はそれからはずれています。

Comment: なるほど。確かにベスト回答を選ぶ際に主観が入る、というのは鋭いご指摘です。1つ思うのは、それはSOのあらゆる質問にも言えないか、という点です。どんな客観的・技術的な質問でも、どちらかと言うとSOは先勝ちの要素が大きく、必ずしも最善の回答とは言えないケースを散見します。そして、そのベスト回答の恣意性を補足するためのSOのシステムが、各回答へのvoteではないでしょうか。SOのQ&Aは、質問とベスト回答だけでなく、総体で見るべきものだと思っています。

Comment: 仰る通りで、質問の内容次第の面もあり、また寄せられる回答次第で質問自体への評価も変わるかと思います。そこで1つ問題なのは、何も回答が寄せられる前に質問にマイナス票が付いてしまうと、質問自体がクローズされてそれ以上回答できなくなる点です。もし寄せられる回答次第で価値の高いQ&Aになりうるなら、質問への性急なマイナス票は慎む必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: @TadayoshiSato 質問のクローズは、質問への down-vote ではなくクローズ票によって決まるものだと思います。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 言葉が不正確でした。はい、言いたかったのは「マイナス票」でなく「クローズ票」ですね。クローズ票5つで「改善待ち」になり、回答を受け付けなくなります。上の趣旨からは、downvote は大いにやっていただいていいですが、クローズ票の投票には慎重になるべきです。

Comment: @TadayoshiSato あまり慎重になる必要はありません。そのためのレビュワーですし、レビューを通ったと言うことはソレ相応の理由があるわけです。（クローズされたことで今回の質問／回答を修正されたわけですよね？）当事者以外分からないような質問になるくらいなら早く直してSOに受け入れられる質問にしてべきかと

Comment: @Myaku それはレビューが全面的に正しい前提のお話ですよね。今回問題提起しているのは、曲がりなりにもそのレビューに少し再考の余地があるのでは、ということです。もちろん、レビューがすべて納得の行くものであれば、SOの仕組み自体は素晴らしいと思います。自分自身がレビューする立場になることもありますが、自分も常にそのレビューが正しいとは思っていません。

Comment: @TadayoshiSato 今回のレビューが正しく無いと感じているのでしょうか？私は正しいと感じております。そもそもStackOverflowはユーザのコミュニティで成り立っているので正しい・正しくないはユーザの総意で決定します。信用度の高いユーザの中の5人がレビューすることでそれを汲み取っています。正しく無いレビューが通らない仕組みはあるので、躊躇するよりクローズ票を投じるべきです。

Comment: @TadayoshiSato また、レビューに疑問があった場合のためにMETAもありますし、閉じること自体もステータスの移行にしかすぎず、正しい内容に修正されることで再度公開もされます。閉じられることは悪いことでは有りません。

Comment: @Myaku まさに、そこら辺の意見が分かれているのでこのMETAで私がこの議論を開始した訳です。ちなみに、元質問は私の疑義を反映いただけたのか（私が質問を改善したのもありますが）クローズは撤回されています。また、downvoteと同じくらいupvoteもいただいています。意見が分かれている証拠ではないでしょうか。SOの現行システムに何も疑問を感じられていないようですが、SOの運営自体はコミュニティに委ねられる方針のようなので、ここで議論を意義はあるでしょう。

Comment: @Myaku なお、yohjpさんからいただいた回答にぶら下がっているyohjpさんご自身のコメントもご一読ください。信用度の高い方でも、SO-JPの「主観性」に関するレビューに疑義を持たれている方も少なからずいるようです。

Comment: @TadayoshiSato 現在のレビュー意識について話しております。理想はそうでしょうが現状関係有りません。(そもそも其方にもメリットデメリットあるかと思います)。議題は該当の質問に対するレビューが正当か？というものですので、もし現状のSOのレビューに対して意識改革をしたいのであれば別の議題でお願いします。

Answer (score 9):

> 「〜の次期メジャーバージョンアップの目玉機能は何か？」という質問は主観的か

目玉機能という言葉尻は、少なからず主観的と捉えられる可能性があると感じました。

ただし、“この質問がクローズされるべき”とは思いません。ヘルプセンター [どのような質問は避けるべきですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) に列挙されている、「建設的」要素を満足する質問たり得ると考えます。同基準のバックグラウンドは「[いい「主観的」、よくない「主観的」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485/%e5%8f%82%e8%80%83%e3%83%96%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e8%a8%98%e4%ba%8b-%e3%81%84%e3%81%84-%e4%b8%bb%e8%a6%b3%e7%9a%84-%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-%e4%b8%bb%e8%a6%b3%e7%9a%84)」で詳しく説明されてます。

> 一部の主観的な質問は許されますが、「主観的」とは「何でもあり」という意味ではありません。すべての主観的な質問は建設的であることが期待されます。どういう意味でしょうか?建設的で主観的な質問とは以下のようなものです。
>
> - 「なぜ」と「どうやって」を説明する回答を引き出す
> - 短い回答ではなく長い回答がつきやすい
> - 建設的で公正、かつ偏らないトーンである
> - 意見よりも経験を共有することを歓迎する
> - 意見が事実と参考資料で裏付けされていると主張する
> - 単なる思慮のない交流を楽しむものではない

本件に照らすと、単なる新機能の列挙にとどまる回答ではなく、なぜその機能が望まれていたかや、どのような問題をいかに解決するかなどが説明されていれば良いのではないでしょうか。その意味で、自己回答内容にも問題がある（少なくともdownvoteに値する）とは思いません。

Comment: 個人的意見ですが、現時点のスタックオーバーフローは **過度に** 「主観的」質問を避けているように感じます。StackOverflow本家では他メタサイトへ主観的質問を誘導することができますが、StackExchangeではスタックオーバーフローが唯一の日本語ローカライズ版ということを鑑みると、若干の主観的要素を許容する懐の広さくらい有ってもいいのではとも感じます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。私もそう思います。とくにSO-Jはまだ立ち上げ間もない状況で、過度に警察的に「主観的」質問を取り締まるようなフェーズではないと思います。私の元質問も、実は [apache-camel] というタグがまだSO-Jに存在しなかったため敢えてした質問でもあったのですが、そこでこういう状況に出会うとは何とも皮肉に感じました。

Answer (score 7):

クローズ投票をした一人です。私がクローズをした理由を示します。

「目玉機能」という言葉が非常に主観的に感じました。
回答の中で「そんな機能よりこの機能のほうが目玉だ！」という論争になる可能性があると考えクローズ票を投稿しました。

一機能しか追加されないようなライブラリのバージョンアップならまだしも、今回のCamelは久々のメジャーバージョンアップを予定しているためいくつかの大型の改修が含まれそうです。
そうなってくるといろいろと目玉と言っても見るポイントで評価が変わってくるのではないでしょうか？

コミュニティで「目玉機能はこれだ」という定義をしていたら私の見落としですのでご指摘願います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘の意味は納得しました。うーむ、「目玉機能」に代わるもっと良い表現はないでしょうか…　
元質問への自己回答でも示していますが、Camel 3については、コミュニティである程度、注目機能はリストアップされています。 http://camel.apache.org/camel-30-ideas.html こうした情報や、ML、内外のMeetupでの議論を元に、少なくとも開発者間ではある程度コンセンサスが出来上がっていると考えていました。それを踏まえた上で、「目玉機能」の選別に多少主観が入ったとしても、いくつか回答が集まれば、全体として最終的にMECEなQ&Aになるだろうというのが私の楽観的な見方です。そうであれば、総体として「個人的な意見や感想で回答が発散する」という事態にはならないだろうと思います。
このメタ質問については、ご指摘の通り、主観的か否かは対象のプロジェクトによりケースバイケース、という結論になるでしょうか。

Comment: もう1つあえて付け加えるとすれば、「そんな機能よりこの機能のほうが目玉だ！」という論争を想定するのは、あくまで想定回答者がユーザでしかない（コア開発者が不在）というのを前提にしていないでしょうか。もしプロジェクトリードなどのコア開発者（またはそれに近い人）がこの種の質問に回答してくれるのであれば、それが主観か客観か、という議論はそもそも必要ないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね。確かにユーザからみた目玉機能でしか想定していないですね。そういう意味だと「開発者もしくはベンダーからみた目玉機能は何でしょうか」という質問だったらより主観は入りづらいものになるとは思います。

Answer (score 2):

**開発している当事者の視点での目玉機能**があるのならば、公式サイト上などの
より適切な場所で情報を発信してくれた方がいいのではと思いました。

ですので、利用者視点で目玉機能を挙げる=取捨選択するなかでどうしても主観的な
意見になるのではと思い、元質問にもクローズを投票した次第です。

Comment: なるほど。確かに公式サイトにすべてあるのが望ましいですが、ちなみに元の質問は、そもそも自分が作り上げたものではなく、他の方からいただいた質問を私が代わりに挙げたものです。Camel 3の情報は、私が回答でも示しているようにある程度公式情報として既に上がっているのですが、必ずしも誰もが公式情報にアンテナを張り巡らせている訳ではないということです。そうしたユーザをSOで否定する必要はないと思います。

Comment: なお、私の元質問にクローズ票を投じた方であれば、ぜひ当時の意図だけでなく、私がこのメタで上げている議論についてもどう思われるか意見をいただきたいです。