# この質問はどうやったらオントピックにできますか？

Tags: 討議

[データ構造とアルゴリズムは実務ではどんなシーンで役立つのか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54837/)

この質問のタイトルを見たとき、「数学は社会に出て役に立つのか？」というような、
プログラミングの入り口にたったばかりの人を彷彿とさせるような興味深い質問だと思いました。
"こんな知識が一体なんの役に立つんだ"という気持ちは分からなくもないです。

オフトピックということで、質問できるトピックについてヘルプを見ました。

[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

"アルゴリズムに関する問題"であり、疑問が具体的なので回答も出来そう。
私の観点で照らし合わせると特に問題があるようには感じられませんでした。

ただ、人によって回答が変わるかもしれないという点で、
次のヘルプを見たときに"主観的な質問"と捕らえられるかもしれないなとは思いました。

[どのような質問は避けるべきですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

私としては今後出てくる初学者のための参考になりそうですし、
クローズする必要はないかなぁと感じているのですが、
クローズされていて、オープンするためにどうしたらいいというアドバイスも無かったので"どうすればいいのかな？"といったところです。

この質問はどの点が問題で、どういう風に直せばオントピックに出来そうでしょうか？

---

**追記**

この質問のクローズ理由は「オフトピック」です。
勿論、既に回答いただいている通り、(よくない)主観的で回答できなくなりそうな部分や
回答範囲が広すぎるという点についてはクローズ・修正候補ですが、
こちらを修正したところでオフトピックという点は変わっていないように思えます。
もしオフトピックが間違いなら再オープンしたいです。
その後、"主観的な回答しか集まらない"ということでクローズされるなら、それはそれでいいと思ってます。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

私は[避けるべき質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)のこの辺りには少なくとも該当していると考えます:

> - 質問と一緒に回答も提示され、さらに他の回答を期待している:「私は ______ に ______ を使用しています。皆さんは何を使用しますか?」
> - 解決すべき実際の問題がない:「他の人が私と同じように感じるか興味があります。」

「データ構造やアルゴリズムは必要ない(あるいは必要さは極めて限定的だ)」という結論を自身で出している以上、他者が回答すべきことは無いかと。

直面している問題から生じた質問ではなくて単なる興味本位のアンケートであると自分は感じました。

---

> この質問はどうやったらオントピックにできますか？

何を解決したいのかが明確になること、でしょうかね…？
タイトルの

> データ構造とアルゴリズムは実務ではどんなシーンで役立つのか？

が明らかになった結果どうなるのかというのがよくわかりません。他人が必要だと主張したからといって自分には不要であることに変わりは無いと思うのですが。

Answer (score 6):

まずは Sieg さんも挙げた通り「(○○)の教科は社会に出て役に立つのか？」に似た疑問だという印象を私も持ちました。件の質問では対象を「データ構造やアルゴリズム」としていますが、何かのプログラミング言語等も当てはまりそうです。

しかしこの形式の質問は「関わる業務や課題に左右される」というのが、答える側の率直な意見だろうと思います。

また、webアプリのフレームワークやiOSなどかなり広い範囲に言及しながら「実務でどう役立つのか？」というのも"範囲が広すぎる"印象を与える原因です。
[774RRさんが回答している](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/54838/3060)ようにある程度対象が絞られていれば回答も付きやすいでしょう。範囲が広すぎる質問には、せっかく苦労して回答しても疑問を解決できない場合があるので、双方にとって好ましくありません。

---

「"アルゴリズムに関する問題"だからオントピックじゃないか？」と言うことですが、単にアルゴリズムに言及していればいいというものではなく、回答可能な問題であることが求められます。
(例えばAとBのアルゴリズムではどうして実行速度に違いが出るの？とか)

Answer (score 2):

私は現状の内容でもクローズまではしなくてよいという立場です。

個人的には、こちらのご質問はオフトピックではないと思っています。プログラミングに関する、現実的な質問だからです。

「主観的な質問しか集まらない」というのならまだ分かります。ただ、こちらのご質問はどちらかというと建設的な主観的質問として扱えるのではないかと考えています。

[参考ブログ記事: いい「主観的」、よくない「主観的」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1485/19110)

> 1. 建設的な主観的質問は、「なぜ（why）」「どうやって（how）」を説明する答えをひきだす。(後略)
>
> (中略)
>
> 4. 建設的な主観的質問は、意見より経験を共有する回答をひきだす。(後略)
> 5. 建設的な主観的質問は、意見というものは事実や参考資料で裏打ちされているべきだと強調する。(後略)

Comment: 私も「オフトピック」に入れた一人ですが、オフトピックとしてのクローズは間違いだったなと思います(再オープン票を入れました)。ただ、「建設的か」というと否定的です（質問者さんの職場の不満とも取れる本文・主張の強さ・回答へのコメントを見た総合的な印象から）

Answer (score 2):

meta 的「回答」では全くないですが、元質問にコメント付けた当事者として

大学時代に同期から同じような質問を受けましたし、就職してからも後輩君に同じような質問を受けました。んで、オイラの答えは

「プログラムの動作速度は価値である（金になる）」
「適切なプログラムが書けるプログラマはの価値は高い（給料なり周りの信頼が上がる）」
「専門家として出来て当たり前なことが出来ない奴は淘汰対象」

です。

「動作速度」は「信頼性」「確実性」あるいはあなたの好きな任意の言葉に代わっていいです。

この手の質問（明確な答えがないお悩み相談みたいなもの）が jSO で好まれないのは事実なんですけど、では StackExchange の日本語サイトは現時点で無いので、許容してもいいんぢゃねーの、とは内心思いました。でもまあそういうのは teratail でも池、ってのも何となく同意。

# っていうか回答書いている間にクローズ票が複数ついてたのが微妙にショック。
 # 投稿後にクローズされちゃったのはまあ仕方ないかなーと思いました。
 # でも内心思うのは「ちょっと狭量にすぎませんか？」
 # teratail ほどフリーダムになる必要は無いっすけど。

役に立つ場面が「無いことの証明」は悪魔の証明なので困難ですけど
「有ることの証明」は一例を挙げればよいのでああいう回答を書いてみました。

Comment: METAだったか何処かで誰かも言ってたのを見た記憶があるのですが、ストイックにルールガチガチにクローズにする理由を探すのではなくて、774RRさんの言う通りコミュニティでもう少し許容してあげてもいいのではないかと思います。ベータで人も少ないわけですし……

Comment: この回答の趣旨からは逸れますが、 teratail においても、当該質問のような「明確な答えがない質問」は、[避けるべき質問](https://teratail.com/help/avoid-asking)に分類される可能性があります。